# Radiative Transfer Equation with Thomson Scattering

Tags: astrophysics, radiation

I'm trying to understand this problem where I'm supposed to define the RTE for a star which surface radiates isotropically and is surrounded by a planetary nebula; gas sphere made up of ionized hydrogen which also *only* scatters the radiation (Thomson scattering).

Besides the RTE for the star radiation I'm also asked to define the source function of the nebula and specify which sources contribute to the function.

This is what I know. The specific intensity of an object with an isotropic radiation is equal by definition to the mean intensity.

$J_v = I_v$

Also, for pure scattering the source function is

$S_\nu =\frac{j_\nu}{\zeta_\nu} = J_\nu$

Then generally the RTE is given by

$\frac{dI_\nu}{ds} = -\alpha_\nu I_\nu + j_\nu$

which now becomes 
$\frac{dI_\nu}{ds} = -\zeta_\nu J_\nu + j_\nu  = -\zeta_\nu J_\nu + \zeta_\nu J_\nu$

but it doesn't make sense. I don't know how to proceed.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: How does $\alpha_\nu I_\nu=\zeta_\nu J_\nu$?

Comment: $\zeta_\nu$ is equivalent to $\alpha_\nu$ and $I_\nu$ is equal to $J_\nu$ since radiation is isotropic. The equation for scattering is usually $\frac{dI_\nu}{ds} = -\zeta_\nu (I_\nu - J_\nu)$